# PHP / JSON issues

Tags: php, json

I am having a strange issues currently with PHP / JSON
Everything worked fine till yesterday, havent changed anything in the coding.

Let me explain the whole situation. 
I created an order processing system with JSON being used for fetching information and updating right away the display. 
So one of the features are, search for customer if not customer account is found, create new one and use that in the order right away.

Till yesterday this worked without any issues, if no customer account is found another screen is open and the information is filled in, and the account is saved.

It uses JSON to check if the customer account exists. 
Then the user is returned to the main screen with the account # already filled just to press enter to fill in the name, address, phone etc (JSON is used for this as well).

Now JSON doesnt find the information, even though i am checking the database and the customer account is saved. I open directly the JSON file in order to see if there are any issues when the update of the database was done, but it shows null.

When i refresh this page, it finds the appropriate information.

Here is the code used to encode the JSON

```php
$stud_id = $_GET["id"];
$qr = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE account = '$stud_id';";

$res= mysql_query($qr);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
    $stud_arr["customer_name"] = $row["name"];
    $stud_arr["customer_address"] = $row["address"];
    $stud_arr["customer_city"] = $row["city"];
    $stud_arr["customer_state"] = $row["state"];
    $stud_arr["customer_zipcode"] = $row["zipcode"];
    $stud_arr["customer_phone"] = $row["phone"];
    $stud_arr["customer_email"] = $row["email"];
    $stud_arr["terms"] = $row["terms"];

 header('Content-type: application/json;');
      echo json_encode($stud_arr);
```

here is the function that uses this code:

```js
var id_val = m;
var url = "json.php?id=" + id_val + "&act=sales";

$("#customer_account").attr("disabled", "disabled");
$("#ajaxLoader").show();
$.getJSON(url, function(json) {

  $.each(json, function(k, v) {
    document.getElementById(k).value = v;
  });

  $("#ajaxLoader").hide();

  if (isObjectEmpty(json)) {
    alert("No customer found, please enter the customer account, or search for customer")
    var answer = confirm("Do you want to create new account?", "yes", "no");

    document.getElementById('customer_account').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('customer_account').focus();
    if (answer == true) {
      window.open('addNewCustomer.php?account=' + document.getElementById('customer_account').value).focus();
    }
  } else {

    var url4 = "getAllShipTo.php?id=" + document.getElementById('customer_account').value;
    var counterTemp = 1;
    document.getElementById('ship_to').options[0] = new Option("Select Ship To", '');
    $.getJSON(url4, function(json) {

      $.each(json, function(k, v) {

        document.getElementById('ship_to').options[counterTemp] = new Option(v, k);
        document.getElementById('ship_to').options[counterTemp].id = counterTemp;
        counterTemp++;

      });
    });
    document.getElementById('customer_account').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('searchCustomer1').onclick = "";
    document.getElementById('division').focus();
  }

});
```

so when first i open the order entry screen, this is triggered

```
 window.open('addNewCustomer.php?account=' + document.getElementById('customer_account').value).focus();
```

Then when the customer account is entered, and i know it is saved, again the same is triggered

```
 window.open('addNewCustomer.php?account=' + document.getElementById('customer_account').value).focus();
```

but if i open the json.php with the necessary information in the address bar, first it shows null but then it show the correct values, see bellow.

```
{"customer_name":"null","customer_address":"null","customer_city":"null","customer_state":"null","customer_zipcode":"null","customer_phone":"null","customer_email":"null","terms":"null"}
```

after the refresh:

```
{"customer_name":"te","customer_address":"te","customer_city":"te","customer_state":"te","customer_zipcode":"te","customer_phone":"te","customer_email":"","terms":"COD"}
```

So i realy dont know what is going on, and how to solve this issue.

Any help i will appreciate it, thank you.

Comment: *"but if i open the json.php with the necessary information in the address bar, first it shows null but then it show the correct values"* - So it seems that json.php is the one failing. Hard for us to say why, without its code.

Comment: well i put the code above, the necessary PHP code for the encoding of the JSON as well as the JSON javascript part that decodes and populates the necessary fields.
the issue is that in the online system, i cant do refresh, maybe if i logoff/login, then it might show me correct, but like this no.

so steps are query DB, get null, Insert into DB, get null again from JSON, refresh, Get correct value.

If you understand what i am saying

Comment: I overlooked/misinterpreted the PHP. Sorry. If I look at it now, it looks simple enough and it seems hardly possible that it failed. Two possible reasons: 1) The first time you didn't pass the right id. 2) The customer was not saved (committed) yet when you tried to query it.

Comment: i checked that already, i passed the right ID, and the customer was saved, because i check the back end of the database, and it exists there, so  the query should return the result.

What it looks like to me is that it keeps the previous info, or previous state of the database, even though i havent had any issues till yesterday like this, in a matter of seconds apart, i can save a customer (commit) and retrieve the information back to the sales order.

What could have changed that? what can affect the PHP/JSON like this? have u heard of any issue like this from anyone?

Comment: can it be the hosting, or the too many queries? There can be at most 5-6 queries at the same time, that to my opinion should not affect the database or anything.

Even if there are 20-30 concurent queries, it should not affect and cause issue like this.

Or am i wrong?

Comment: another thing i noticed, is that this is not the issue, if i create the customer, but i go on another computer and try to search for the customer, it will work, it is just on the same computer, where u create the customer and where you try to retrieve it, that it causes the issue. 

What can that be? Any clues?